# How to add new property to a powershell object

Tags: arrays, powershell

Say I have a object with the following properties:

Name
School
Address
Phone

And I have it filled with 100 entries. Now I want to add another property to it, like ZipCode.

How do I add that to my objectso that when I run a foreach I will have the option to call myobject.Zip and assign a value to it?

To give a better idea, I am importing an excel sheet to an object, like this:

```
$file = "\Desktop\AccessReviewReportPRE.csv" 
$fileContent = Import-csv $file
```

Now when I loop the object printing everything I have this(multiple times of course)

```
Title/Name            : x
LoginName             : x
PermissionType        : x
Permissions           : x
URL                   : x
Site/List/Folder/Item : x
```

And I want to add a new property so that I will have

```
Title/Name            : x
LoginName             : x
PermissionType        : x
Permissions           : x
URL                   : x
Site/List/Folder/Item : x
NewProperty           : x
```

For all items inside the object

Comment: How was the object created? What is its type?

Comment: Just edited with the info

Comment: `Import-Csv $file | select *,ZipCode` or use `Add-Member` on the items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just loop over the object and add another member to the object, something like this:

```
foreach ($item in $fileContent) {
    $item | add-member –membertype NoteProperty –name SomeName –value SomeValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no need for the value to initially be unique per item, just use `| Select-Object` along with a custom property.

```
$File = "\Desktop\AccessReviewReportPRE.csv" 
$FileContent = Import-csv $File

$Content = $FileContent  | Select *, @{label = 'NewProperty'; expression = {'NewValue'}}
```

You can of course put whatever code you like in the expression code block instead of a static value.